# Any good open source online RPG starter kit for development?

Tags: toolkit

Does anyone know of a good open source toolkit that allows level designer and graphic designer or someone with basic programming experience to create multiplayer online Role Playing Game ? The game can be a simple 2D interface in a 2d virtual world.

I know Microsoft have a starter kit something like the following :

http://creators.xna.com/en-US/starterkit/roleplayinggame

that allows developer to create RPG game running on XBox platform but i am looking more on multiplayer role playing game on the web platform where player can play directly with their browser.

regards
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

### Tried these??...

---

- RPG MAKER for XP

  > http://tkool.jp/products/rpgxp/eng/
- ECLIPSE MMORPG creator

  > http://www.freemmorpgmaker.com/index.php

Also as a stand-alone game developer (which i presume you are) i would suggest You go through these for a good grasp of the challenges ahead:

> - [Game Development & Production](http://www.kmitl.ac.th/~s8050341/gprog/res/presentation/L02Extra/game%20development%20and%20production.pdf)
> - [Game Developer's Open Source Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584504978)

---

**UPDATE:** You might be interested in **[Quake-Live](http://www.quakelive.com/#home)**

For a few sample of **Quake Live** on Youtube:

> http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=quake+live+demo&aq=f

Comment: Thanks for the information. Maybe to be more specific, i am looking for browser based MMORPG game development toolkit and most toolkit requires player to download a standalone client. Something similar to the following game :
http://en.grepolis.com/

Answer (score 0):

[RPG Toolkit](http://www.toolkitzone.com/toolkit.php) seems to be a good one too

Answer (score 0):

For 2D single-player:

http://rpgjs.com/

For 2D MMO:

http://browserquest.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) is free for you to develop games for the web (and desktop I think), you can later upgrade your account in order to deploy your game into more platforms. Really easy to use and the programing is friendly enough for you to learn (lots of tutorials everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Pokemon Essentials is good for pokemon games, but I have used it for many other RPG games.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlnzaEhH5cI <-- It's in the description